# Save an excel file as data frame after input()

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to take the file path input from the user, and then do manipulations on the file using `pandas`.

As of now, I do the following,

```
import sys
import os
import pandas as pd

user_input = input("Enter the path of your file: ")

assert os.path.exists(user_input), "I did not find the file at, "+str(user_input)
f = open(user_input,'r+')
```

I am **assuming** (I guess, I am going wrong here), that the file is getting saved temporarily in `f`.

After which I do the following,

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(f)
```

Which does not work.

The error that is get is,

```
Enter the path of your file: C:/Users/MyPC/Desktop/Files/Data/11.05.2018/data.xls
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-9bfb9b9b2c74> in <module>()
      7 assert os.path.exists(user_input), "I did not find the file at, "+str(user_input)
      8 f = open(user_input,'r+')
----> 9 xl = pd.ExcelFile(f)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py in __init__(self, io, **kwds)
    289         elif not isinstance(io, xlrd.Book) and hasattr(io, "read"):
    290             # N.B. xlrd.Book has a read attribute too
--> 291             data = io.read()
    292             self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=data)
    293         elif isinstance(self._io, compat.string_types):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py in decode(self, input, final)
     21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
     22     def decode(self, input, final=False):
---> 23         return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
     24 
     25 class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 545: character maps to <undefined>
```

Can someone help me?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to save your input as pandas DataFrame and then save it in excel format. I guess the format of the input file is excel as well. I would do the following:

```
import sys
import os
import pandas as pd

user_input = input("Enter the path of your file: ")

assert os.path.exists(user_input), "I did not find the file at, "+str(user_input)

df = pd.read_excel(user_input)
```

You can now just run `df` to see the data frame.

For saving, please, take a look at this documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: just edited the answer as I noticed you already printed the input file extention

Comment: The process that you have mentioned will involve entering the **file name** again. However, I am already taking the file as the input as `f`.

Comment: all right, what if you pass the file as df = pd.read_excel(user_input)?

Comment: what is the output of print(user_input) ?

Comment: it should be a string with the input file name. I tried it and was compatible with the request of pandas. I'm editing my answer to make it more compliant